# re:replace with & does not include ampersand in replacement

Tags: erlang

```
43> re:replace(Pid, "<", "&lt", [{return,list}]).
"<lt0.188.0>"
```

I'm trying to remove the < and > from my PID to provide a HTML friendly link.

With the above code lt is inserted, but the < seems not to have been deleted and the & is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is a special character in `re:replace`'s replacement string (as documented [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#replace-4)) which inserts the whole matched string, which in this case is `<`. You'll need to escape the `&`. You also forgot to add the `;` after `&lt`.

```
1> Pid = pid_to_list(self()).
"<0.63.0>"
2> re:replace(Pid, "<", "\\&lt;", [{return,list}]).
"&lt;0.63.0>"
```